# How to inline list ul in Foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I cannot seem to find the right way to inline list a 'ul' (and it's li elements, so they appear horizontally instead of vertically) in Foundation 6  (F5 has a 'inline-list' class)

```
    <footer class="text-center">
    <div class="row" id="footer-nav">
        <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
            <h4>Footer nav area 1</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
            <h4>Footer nav area 1</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
            <h4>Footer nav area 1</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
            <h4>Footer nav area 1</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Nav link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>        

    <hr class="footer-divider">

    <div class="row" id="footer-social-company">                       
        <div class="columns large-12 medium-12"> 
            <!-- how to center align the following ul? -->
            <ul class="menu align-center" id="social-list">
                <li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">google+</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">linkedin</a></li>                    
            </ul>

            <div class="" id="company">© My Company</div>
        </div>
    </div>                 

</footer>
```

OK so I found this:
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36854-where-is-inline-list-in-foundation-6

But adding class 'menu' to the UL element makes it full width, losing the ability to centre-align the ul properly (I want to be able to exactly center the ul).  Accordng to docs, you can either left or right align but not center align?
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html#item-alignment

Thanks for help

Comment: The class 'align-center' in the ul doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

They changed it to .menu.simple

```
<ul class="menu simple">
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html#

Comment: Adding 'simple' didn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

What worked was using following on the parent div above the ul:

```
<div class="columns large-4 medium-4 large-centered small-centered">
```